# How to accumulate using a Lambda function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to accumulate the numbers in a vector using a multiplication lambda.

What is my error? I get 1 as the result, instead of 24 (= 1*2*3*4). My approach is as follows:

```
std::function<float(float a, int x)> func;
std::vector<int> m{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // <-- Multiply: 1*2*3*4 = 24

float accumulation = 1.0f;
func = [&accumulation, &m](float a, int i) {
    accumulation = a * *m.begin()++;
    return accumulation;
};
accumulation = accumulate(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), accumulation, func);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to accumulate a result using for\_each in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65580272/how-to-accumulate-a-result-using-for-each-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be:

```
auto accumulation = std::accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 1, std::multiplies{});
```

Your `func` does a lot of odd stuff and I have no idea what you hope for with `accumulation = a * *m.begin()++;` or why you leave `i` unused. This would be more like it:

```
auto func = [](int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs * rhs; };

auto accumulation = std::accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 1, func);
```

Or if you want to do it with `float`s:

```
auto func = [](float lhs, float rhs) { return lhs * rhs; };

auto accumulation = accumulate(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), 1.f, func);
```