# How to accumulate a result using for_each in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reproduce what `accumulate` does using `for_each`. However I don't understand what is the problem in the `for_each` version:

```
int main() {
    std::function<float(float, int)> func = [](float a, int i) {return a * i; };
    std::vector<int> m{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // <-- Multiply: 1*2*3*4 = 24


    float accumulationUsingAccumulate = 1.0f;
    accumulationUsingAccumulate = accumulate(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), accumulationUsingAccumulate, func);
    std::cout << "[Accumulate] Result = " << accumulationUsingAccumulate << std::endl;
    

    float accumulationUsingForEach = 1.0f;
    std::for_each(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), [&accumulationUsingForEach, &m, &func]() {
        accumulationUsingForEach = func(accumulationUsingForEach, *m.cbegin()++);
    });
    std::cout << "[For Each] Result = " << accumulationUsingForEach << std::endl;
}
```

Does the outer lambda function in the second version require an argument?

The following error messages are returned:

[image]

Comment: [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) wants function (including lambda function) that takes one argument. Why not give that?

Comment: Just take an argument `int i`, and use that instead of `*m.cbegin()++`. Also, please add the error message when the code doesn't compile.

Comment: (and you already got an answer) you know that you should post the error messages as copyable text as well, right?

Answer (score 1):

`std::for_each` third argument, unary function, should accept current element

```
float accumulationUsingForEach = 1.0f;
std::for_each(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), [&accumulationUsingForEach, &func](const float& a) {
    accumulationUsingForEach = func(accumulationUsingForEach, a);
});
std::cout << "[For Each] Result = " << accumulationUsingForEach << std::endl;
```